# C# Task.Delay wait period before starting

Tags: c#

Was wondering if there was a way to have Task.Delay() wait before a certain timeperiod (e.g. minutes) before starting the wait interval?  I was thinking something similar to Timer where you can specify a "dueTime" before it actually starts. So something like Task.Delay(5, 10, cancellationToken), where it will delay every 10 minutes but starting the count 5 minutes later.

Comment: How is that different from two delays, one of 5 and one of 10?  If you want to delay twice, just call `Delay` twice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Task.Delay` isn't periodic to begin with.  One Task, one wakeup.

Are you calling it in a loop?  Call it once before entering the loop, with the alternate delay.

e.g. change

```
while (true) {
   await Task.Delay(N);
   DoStuff();
}
```

to

```
await Task.Delay(X);
while (true) {
    DoStuff();
    await Task.Delay(Y);
}
```